# Looping another function names

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, for-loop

i have :

```
  Public Function Position1 (button, blabla)
     button.location = New Point(3,9)
  Return blabla
  End Function

  Public Function Position2 (button, blabla)
      button.location = New Point(3,50)
  Return blabla
  End Function

  Public Function Position3 (button, blabla)
      button.location = New Point(3,91)
  Return blabla
  End Function
```

and so on until Function Position100

i want to call these functions and make the code simpler with loop "For .... Next"

so please tell me to fix this code :

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click and so on....
  For x = 1 to 100
     positionx(button1,"filled")
  Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: Are your functions similar in what they do? Show some code for a few of them...

Comment: yes, they do similar code, only with different coordinate

Comment: Add the point corodinates as a parameter into one single function, and have a list of points to iterate through...

Comment: yes, i know we can do that, but i'm just curious whether this is possible to iterate another function names in loop for-next

Answer (score 0):

Add the point co-ordinates as a parameter into one single function, and have a list of points to iterate through..